# How to display a text in the lock screen?

Tags: android, lockscreen

It seem that is now possible to write some text inside the lockscreen in the place where the alarm is usually written.

Please have a look red area in the below image.

[image]

Comment: Would you like to set it manual or programmatically?

Comment: What code/content did you find when trying yourself?

Answer (score 2):

This is supported on android 4.2 and up.
You need to implement it via an App Widget. You can checkout the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen

Depending on your requirements, you could possibly use Notifications, which appear on the lockscreen.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Lock screen app widgets were dropped in Android 5.0.

Comment: In that case, notifications are the way to go. You can create a persistent notification that can't be dismissed. This would effectively allow you to add a message to your lockscreen.

Comment: i want to show how much time the phone has been locked, it is posible to modify that notification? or when i create that notification it stay fixed?